# Decrease dimension of ParallelMapDataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tpu

```
def get_training_dataset():
    lst = [flip, rotate, color]
    dataset = load_dataset(TRAINING_FILENAMES, labeled=True)  
    for data_augment in lst:
        dataset = dataset.map(data_augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE) 
    tf.squeeze(dataset, axis=0)
    print(dataset.shape)
    dataset = dataset.map(flip, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)  
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset
```

The dataset format is **ParallelMapDataset** but when I try to use this code which added one dimension to dataset, e.g my shape is (512, 512, 3) but it returns shape (1, 512, 512, 3).
The **flip**, **rotate** and **color** function is like below:

```
def flip(image, label):
    print("random flip")
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
    return image, label

def color(image, label):
    print("random color")
    image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 0.6, 1.6)
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, 0.05)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, 0.7, 1.3)
    return image, label

def rotate(image, label):
    print("random rotate")
    image = tf.image.rot90(image, tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)),
    return image, label
```

Comment: it's because of `batch`

Comment: @NicolasGervais it means I have to remove it? so how how can I get batch? `dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)`

Comment: A batch adds a dimensions at index 0